# Laravel site works in directory, but isn't opened when move to subdirectory in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, laravel-5

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Here is my virtual host configuration. I edited my root folder from

`/var/www/example.com/public_html/mysite/public`

to

`/var/www/example.com/public_html`

Then I configured my vitualhost for sub directory, as below. Site shows only white screen. Error log, nginx error log is empty.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    error_log /var/www/logs/error.log;

   location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }

    location ^~ /mysite {

            alias /var/www/example.com/public_html/mysite/public;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @mysite;

            location ~* \.php {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            }
    }

    location @mysite {
            rewrite ^/mysite/(.*)$ /mysite/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
```

}

I can't figure out what is a problem.

1) File permissions, laravel configuration had been done correctly.

2) I assume that the problem is with php fpm. But it works, opening the website without subdirectory

I had done same thing before in Ubuntu 14.04. It seems, in Ubuntu 16.04 there is some difference. Also, I checked my public/index.php, added there `die()` function with message. But, again was white screen. Maybe, I miss something while configuring Nginx ?

Answer (score 0):

`/public` is sub-directory of laravel, when you move your project to another directory root should be   `your_project_path/public`

Comment: same thing. In my public_html there are multiple sites as `mySite` and `mySecondSite`. `public` is inside of `mySite` and `mySecondSite`. This is Laravel's index folder.

Comment: document root should be path_to_public_html/mySite/public

Comment: I want to only access to the website  via `mysite.com/mysite`. mysite.com  shoouldn't open sub directory.

Comment: did you restart your nginx server?

Comment: yes. As I told I have done same configuration in Ubuntu 14.04. But can't figure out why it displays white screen?